How to call variable of one function to another function
Trying to call value stored in one variable from function A to function B. Even after defining it as global, not able to get through.
global count

def a():
    count = 1
    print(count)
    return count
a()

def b():
    newcount = count + 2
    print(count)
b()

NameError: name 'count' is not defined


Since a() returns count, you should assign the result: count = a()

The global declaration belongs inside def a(), not at top-level.
